# CommonsMultipartFile or MultipartFile not working once pushed into cloudfoundry

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, cloud-foundry, predix

I am trying to upload a file using CommonsMultipartFile or MultipartFile 
and its working fine in local but not working once pushed into cloudfoundry.

I am testing using Postman.

Here is the sample code:

```
@ResponseBody    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/stw/upload1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String upload1(@RequestParam(name="text",required=true) MultipartFile text){

        return "done";

    }
```

Here is the response in Postman when I am trying to call CF URL.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1494397075418,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException",
  "message": "Required MultipartFile parameter 'text' is not present",
  "path": "/api/stw/upload1"
}
```

Note: I am passing in form-data the key value required in postman.Its working on local but not on CF.
eg: text(Key) - uploadfile(Value)

```
    **Request Header**

    Accept:*/*
    Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,kn;q=0.6
    Cache-Control:no-cache
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:32354
    Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary10QktAWiD1GCsBKF
    DNT:1
    Host:<CF Service URL>
    Origin:chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
    Postman-Token:d22500e6-f0d9-0f29-b981-78a45b6e4524
    Pragma:no-cache
    User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36

**Request Payload**
------WebKitFormBoundary10QktAWiD1GCsBKF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadFile"; filename="error.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain


------WebKitFormBoundary10QktAWiD1GCsBKF--
```

Comment: How are you running it locally?  What version of Java & Tomcat?  Do these match the versions being installed by the Java build pack when you run your app on CF (hint: Java build pack will display versions it's installing during staging).  Probably would also help to see the request you're sending.  Maybe capture it from Chrome Dev tools, or include the `curl` command to replicate it.

Comment: For local I am calling the service from Postman. Both Java and tomcat is latest i.e Java8 and tomcat 8.5.

Comment: Request Header
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,kn;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:32354

Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary10QktAWiD1GCsBKF

DNT:1

Host:<CF Service URL>

Origin:chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop

Comment: Can you edit and include that in your initial response so that it get's formatted better?

Comment: Please Check...

Comment: You're not sending a form field named `text`.  You're sending `uploadFile`.  Either change what you're sending in your client or change `@RequestParam(name="uploadFile",required=true)`.  No idea why that would have worked locally.

Comment: Sorry for that. That I was trying some different URL with text . I have the same error. please ignore that uploadFile thats text only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was commons-upload pom dependency.

I was using commons-upload for upload files that was working fine into local but its gave multipart error when pushed to Predix. So after removing it and respective bean configuration and then pushed to Predix it worked fine.